# Finding all complex functions satisfying multiple conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been thinking about this problem for days:

**Problem**

Find all functions $f (z)$ satisfying:

1. $f (z)$ is analytic on ${\Im(z) > 0}$;
2. $f (z)$ is continuous on ${\Im(z) \geq 0}$;
3. $f (z)$ is real–valued on the real axis;
4. $|f (z)| > | \sin(z)|$ on ${\Im(z) > 0}$.

**Solution attempt**

I know that it couldn't be a plain polynomial or rational function because it does not satisfy criteria 4. This is because one could easily show that

$$
|\sin(x + i y)| = \sqrt{(\cosh y)^2 (\sin x)^2 + (\cos x)^2 (\sinh y)^2},
$$

which scales exponentially in the imaginary direction.

Evidently, $A \sin z$ with $A > 1$ satisfies all conditions. I also noticed that e.g. $A \sin z^2$ wouldn't work, since it would not satisfy condition 4, since $\sin x^2 \ngtr \sin x$ on the real line. In fact, I "feel" that $A \sin f(z)$ only satisfies the conditions 1-4. if $f(z) = z$, but I can't prove this.

With the above considerations, my guess is that *only* functions of the form $A \sin z$ with $A > 1$ satisfy all conditions, but I can't prove it rigorously. So the question is:

*How do you find all the functions satisfying conditions 1-4?*

I am also interested in a more systematic solution to these kinds of problems.

**Source**

- https://www.math.sissa.it/sites/default/files/Entrance_Examinations_pdf/ScrittoPhD2019Sep.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from conditions (1)-(3) and the Schwarz reflection principle that $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function in $\Bbb C$.

Then $|f(z)| \ge |\sin(z)|$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$ from condition (4) and the symmetry with respect to the real axis.

Finally use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities to conclude that $\sin(z)/f(z)$ extends to a holomorphic function in $\Bbb C$, and Liouville's theorem to conclude that this quotient is in fact constant.